# Regexp match every string that has 1 DOT in it and ends not with .com /.net /.org

Tags: mysql, regex, phpmyadmin

I made a mistake and replaced all `.com with ''` (nothing) in my database, later I added `.com` to every string without a dot in it.

But sadly this ended up in having urls with subdomains like `wayne.wanyesword.com/something/` going to be `wayne.wanyesword/something/` now

I'd like to find all these domains in phpmyadmin. What do I have to type into REGEX or NOT REGEX search to find all entries where this went wrong?

Comment: I think this could be done much easier if you were using a scripting language such as PHP, where u can select all, apply a regex pattern to check if anything before the first / has .com or .net or .org, and replace it and update your db with the results.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the answer is to pull the original data from the most recent backup of your database from before the date when you made the mistake.